# Is there a video player for OS X that will float to top and avoid the cursor?

Tags: macos, mac, vlc

Is there a video app that can float on top and avoid the cursor? The problem with VLC is that I use the "Float on Top" feature while VLC takes up 1/4 of the screen. However sometimes I would like the access the menus below VLV, and therein lies the problem. I don't want to constantly move VLC just to access the menus below it.

Is there a feature or app that can move the video player out of the way from the cursor and return to its' original position afterwards?

Comment: Have your tried using the Application Switcher, pressing Alt-Tab, to set focus to Finder and the Dock or other open apps?

Comment: @user3439894 yea but it switching doesn't work if "float to top" is active via vlc.

Comment: I tested it before I made the comment and just retested it, even with "Float on Top" checked I can press Alt-Tab and use the Application Switcher.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**afloat**](https://github.com/vjt/afloat). This lets you configure VLC to float on top and be somewhat transparent when you move your mouse over it, as well as allowing clicks to pass through to the application behind.

Comment: How do you run afloat? sry i'm new to GetHub.

Comment: @Eagertolearn See the installation section of the readme (at the bottom of the linked page).

Answer (score 0):

There is a player called MPlayerX (mplayerx.org) that allows you to do just that. It floats on top when playing, but does not float when it is paused. I have no idea why other players STILL do not have this function. I mean it is paused, I do not need to be staring at the still image, and if I did want to keep staring at it I can just keep it on top anyways.

I know the question was asked a while ago, but I found this while trying to see if there was another player, or a way to make VLC behave in this manner, and it seems no one gave a good suggestion.

Hope this helps.